# changing ExpandableListView background in xml

Tags: android, xml, expandablelistview

Hi I cant figure for the life of me to change the background of this to white.

CODE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"

    >

 <ExpandableListView 
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"

        >
</ExpandableListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Make the black here white

[image: ScreenShot]

Probably going have to change the font color to black.

Comment: Can you post the View that you are using as a row too?

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but does that mean the horizontal view?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a screenshot of how it looks now? And perhaps a quick description of how you'd like it to look?

Does it look like you want it to but mess up when you go to scroll the list?

Check out this page for some useful info on using listviews with custom backgrounds: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/listview-backgrounds.html

Comment: added a screenshot! it doesnt change from black!

Comment: may be you have a problem , with Android theme !

Answer (score 0):

try setting the cacheColorHint:"00000000"